# Debug symbols in release mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

On an ASP.NET 2.0 website I log details of unhandled exceptions. I would like to log the source filename and line number, but I don't get this in the stack trace when an exception occurs. The reason for this is that I have debug="false" in the web.config compilation settings (it's a production site), therefore no PDB files are being generated on the server. Is there a way to get ASP.NET to generate the debug symbol files in release mode? I don't want to precompile the site.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I doubt it is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I found an answer. You can set debug="false" to get optimisations, and then set compilerOptions="/debug:pdbonly" in the system.codedom compiler settings to get symbols. Here's the relevant web.config excerpts:

```
<system.web>
  ....
  <compilation debug="false" defaultLanguage="c#">
  ...
  </compilation>
</system.web>
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4"
        type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider,System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        compilerOptions="/debug:pdbonly">
      <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
      <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
    </compiler>
    ...
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Comment: Just FYI, for my ASP.NET 4.0 website project, after poking through the CompilerInfo array (use CompilerInfo[] allCompilerInfo = CodeDomProvider.GetAllCompilerInfo(); to get it), the Version setting is "Version=4.0.0.0" and <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>. Everything else is the same. Moral of the story is your mileage may vary, check your actual settings for your project.

Answer (score 1):

Unless Im missing something the difference between debug & release build are in the optimizations. You should be able to create a normal debug binary with pdb and make sure to enable all the optimization settings in the project settings. Afaik unless theres an exception the pdb file wount be loaded, etc...

Comment: It's a ASP.NET 2.0 web site - I'm not building a binary. All the compilation is done on-the-fly by ASP.NET and controlled by web.config settings. It seems I can either have debug="false" (optimisations but no symbols) or debug="true" (symbols but no optimisations).